# G-SVG doesnt show my Image inside it - react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using `react-native-svg`. I want to show my image inside it but `G` doesnt show it:

```
 <G x={endCoord2.x-widthHeight} y={endCoord2.y-widthHeight}>
          <Image resizeMode='stretch' style={{width:50,height:50,margin:4}} source={{uri: 'https://javacupcake.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/IceCreamConeCupcakes_0307.jpg'}} />
 </G>
```

but below code show a white circle:

```
      <G x={endCoord2.x-widthHeight} y={endCoord2.y-widthHeight}>
        <Circle r={widthHeight}
          cx={widthHeight}
          cy={widthHeight}
          fill="#fff"
          {...this._panResponderShops.panHandlers}
          />
      </G>
```

where is my wrong?

Answer (score 0):

solved:

you should import `Image` from `react-native-svg`:

```
        <Image
           x="5%"
           y="5%"
           width={widthHeight+20}
           height={widthHeight+20}
           preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
           opacity="0.5"
           href={require('../../../images/ics/ic_blue_logo.png')}
           clipPath="url(#clip)"
           />
```

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/blob/master/README.md#image